# Firebase web push notification token not getting

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-notifications

I'm iOS developer not php, i'm implementing Firebase web push notifications for send and receive in web. I'm using xampp and php. For this i followed this tutorial https://www.itwonders-web.com/blog/push-notification-using-firebase-demo-tutorial. Here i created **index1.html** page and placed it in **myphp** folder, then created **firebase-messaging-sw.js** file and places in same folder. I'm getting alert for allow but token is null.

See below screenshot, this is my output.

[image]

Actually here I'm using xampp local host, is it mandatory to run in live website for to get token?

(**My url is :** http://192.168.64.2/myphp/)

My code is

Actually index.html page name not getting alert, that's why i replaced page name index1.html, why i don't know it's not showing any files.

**index1.html**

```
<html>
<title>Firebase Messaging Demo</title>
<style>
div {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="token"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
<div id="notis"></div>
<div id="err"></div>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    MsgElem = document.getElementById("msg")
    TokenElem = document.getElementById("token")
    NotisElem = document.getElementById("notis")
    ErrElem = document.getElementById("err")
    // Initialize Firebase
    // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
    var config = {
        apiKey: "AIza********yMSEK3PM",
        authDomain: "myf*********ject.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://myf*********ject.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "myf******ject",
        storageBucket: "myf********ject.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "67********7"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging
        .requestPermission()
        .then(function () {
            MsgElem.innerHTML = "Notification permission granted." 
            console.log("Notification permission granted.");

            // get the token in the form of promise
            return messaging.getToken()
        })
        .then(function(token) {
            TokenElem.innerHTML = "token is : " + token
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            ErrElem.innerHTML =  ErrElem.innerHTML + "; " + err
            console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
        });

    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log("Message received. ", payload);
        NotisElem.innerHTML = NotisElem.innerHTML + JSON.stringify(payload) 
    });
</script>

<body>
</body>
```

**firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
                   'messagingSenderId': '67******7'
                   });

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
                                  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
                                  // Customize notification here
                                  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
                                  const notificationOptions = {
                                  body: 'Background Message body.',
                                  icon: '/itwonders-web-logo.png'
                                  };

                                  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
                                                                            notificationOptions);
                                  });
```

if possible send detailed tutorial link for Firebase web push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and could resolve this by moving the service worker file to htdocs folder i.e. the root folder

Comment: I did not get the question . Could you explain

Comment: actually I'm using local host xampp to run my web app. Is our web app in live status or local host is enough.

Comment: local host is enough. I executed the same code on localhost xampp

Comment: Ok, but I'm not getting any token, can you please send your test code. Is it possible.

Comment: Can you chat in the chat room?

Comment: Ok, please wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190302/discussion-between-ios-and-webdev).